# A concept question about interior point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space.Can we show all points for set $X$ is the interior points for the set X?

I do as follows: since $X$ itself is an open set $X^o = X$ the LHS is interior point set for set $X$.Hence all point in $X$ is interior?

---

There is a relevant question,we can show $\mathbb{Q}\subset X = \mathbb{R}$ has empty interior,since any neiborhood of the point in $\mathbb{Q}$ must intersect some irrational number hence not contains in $\mathbb{Q}$

But for $\mathbb{Q}\subset X = \mathbb{Q}$ does the result above still holds?that is empty interior or all points are interior?

Comment: Every point of $\mathbb Q$ is an interior point when you consider $\mathbb Q$ as  topological space in its own right (with the usual metric). But No point of $\mathbb Q$ is an interior point in the topology of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy ,thanks can we then show any space $X$ ,set $X$ is second category for space $X$?

Comment: That is certainly false. You are trying to reduce Baire Category Theorem  to a useless result. How did you get such an idea?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy thanks,maybe I have found where I was misleading,since first category does not need union to have empty interior it only need each set in the union to have empty interior

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy I was reading open mapping theorem,if the linear map (between to complete metric space) is onto  then the image $T(X)$ is second category.the complete metric space is necessary, I misunderstood it to hold for any space